# LWP Won't Run in CGI Script

Tags: perl, cgi, lwp

I have a CGI script to load publications from BibBase:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = 'https://bibbase.org/show?bib=http://www.example.com/pubs.bib';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $can_accept = HTTP::Message::decodable;
my $response = $ua->get($url, 'Accept-Encoding' => $can_accept);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print $response->decoded_content;
```

(This is copied from [BibBase](https://bibbase.org/help/) with the exception that the URL is hard-coded.)

I have three webservers running RHEL7 and Apache 2.4 that are configured the same way by Puppet. On all three I can run the script on the command line and get the expected results:

```
[root@server1 cgi-bin]# ./bibbase_proxy2.cgi | head
Content-type: text/html

<img src="//bibbase.org/img/ajax-loader.gif" id="spinner" style="display: none;" alt="Loading.." />

<div id="bibbase">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var bibbase = {
      params: {"bib":"http://www.example.com/pubs.bib","host":"bibbase.org"},
```

When I try to run the script with CGI, I get three different results:

- Server1
  `Unrecognised protocol tcp at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 31.`
- Server2
  `Can't connect to bibbase.org:443 System error at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.`
- Server3
  No http output and the error log says `AH01215: Out of memory!`.

I can't find anything different between the three servers and I can't figure out why the script works fine on the command line and doesn't work when run as a CGI.

I have selinux in permissive mode and it is logging the outgoing request, so I know the script gets that far:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1532465859.921:331235): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=161178 comm="perl" dest=80 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:http_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

For testing, I have set selinux to `disabled` and restarted the server.

Comment: Just to eliminate some potential cul-de-sacs: Does `/usr/bin/env perl` run `/usr/bin/perl`? Are there several Perl installations or just the one belonging to the system at `/usr`? Are the relevant modules reasonably up to date (RHEL7 came out in 2014 unless I'm misinformed)? Test with `perl -mLWP::UserAgent -mHTTP::Message -E'say "$_ ".$_->VERSION  for qw(LWP::UserAgent HTTP::Message)'`

Comment: `perl` is in `/usr/bin/perl`. These are the versions: `LWP::UserAgent 6.05`, `HTTP::Message 6.06`. They are the Redhat-supplied ones, so technically the versions are `6.05-2.el7` and `6.06-6.el7`.

Answer (score 4):

[SE-Linux denied the TCP connection](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Where_to_find_SELinux_permission_denial_details).

```
avc:  denied  { name_connect }
```

> The default access controls for networking by SELinux are based on the labels assigned to TCP and UDP ports and sockets. For instance, the TCP port 80 is labeled with http_port_t (and class tcp_socket). Access towards this port is then governed through SELinux access controls, such as name_connect and name_bind.
>
> When an application is connecting to a port, the name_connect permission is checked. However, when an application binds to the port, the name_bind permission is checked.

Permissive mode or not, Perl is acting like it was denied a TCP connection. `Unrecognised protocol tcp` means `getprotobyname("tcp")` [failed inside IO::Socket::IP](https://metacpan.org/source/PEVANS/IO-Socket-IP-0.39/lib/IO/Socket/IP.pm#L441). That's very, very unusual. One of the ways that can happen is via exactly that SELinux denial.

I'm no SELinux expert, but according to RedHat and Gentoo [some SELinux aware applications will ignore the global permissive setting](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Permissive_versus_enforcing#Differences_in_application_behavior) and go it alone. [RHEL 7 Apache appears to be one of them](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server#sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-The_Apache_HTTP_Server_and_SELinux). It appears to [have its own domain which must be set permissive](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting-fixing_problems).

---

> *On all three I can run the script on the command line and get the expected results:*

There's two reasons for that, and they both have to do with users.

When you run the program you're running as your own user with your own configuration, permissions, and environment variables. In fact, you ran it as `root` which usually bypasses restrictions. When it runs on the server it runs as a different user, probably the web server user with severe restrictions.

In order to do a realistic test, you need to run it as the same user the web server will. You can use `sudo -u` for this. For example, if the user is `apache`...

```
sudo -u apache ./bibbase_proxy2.cgi
```

BTW ***Do not test software as root!*** Not only is it not going to give you sensible results, but if there's a bug in the software there are no safeguards preventing it from wrecking your system.

---

The second problem is `#!/usr/bin/env perl`. That means to run whatever perl is in your `PATH`. `PATH` will be different for different users. Running `./bibbase_proxy2.cgi` may run with one Perl on the command line and a different one via the web server.

In a server environment, use a hard coded path to Perl like `#!/usr/bin/perl`.

Comment: 1. As I mentioned in the question, SELinux is in permissive mode, so this isn't the problem. I only included that line to show that the request is being made by Perl.  
2. I have the same problem when I run as the `apache` user. It works fine when run on the command line and does not work when run as CGI.  
3. I have since hard-coded the path to Perl and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @yakatz The log clearly says SELinux denied the TCP connection. And those Perl errors are consistent with that. `Unrecognised protocol tcp` means `getprotobyname("tcp")` failed inside `IO::Socket::IP` and one of the ways that can happen is via SELinux. It's also possible your server is running your code as something other than `apache`.

Comment: `[root@server3 cgi-bin]# sudo -u apache perl -wle 'print getprotobyname("tcp")'` output is `tcpTCP6`. When I run `getenforce`, it says `Permissive`, so I would expect that even though the log says it was denied, that just means it would be denied if the mode was set to `Enforcing`.

Comment: @yakatz Two possibilities. First, verify what user it's running your code as. Print the real and effective UID of the CGI process. `$<` and `$>`. Second, some applications ignore your SELinux configuration. https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Permissive_versus_enforcing#Differences_in_application_behavior

Comment: @yakatz I think that's the problem. More on [RedHat + Apache + SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server#sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-The_Apache_HTTP_Server_and_SELinux) and [Permissive Domains](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting-fixing_problems).

Comment: Real and effective UIDs are both 48. To check SELinux, I ran `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`. Now the `denied` message isn't logged, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: @yakatz Again, I believe Apache is doing its own thing with SELinux. [It has its own `httpd_t` SELinux domain](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server#sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-The_Apache_HTTP_Server_and_SELinux) and you have to [configure that separately](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting-fixing_problems).

Comment: I ran `semanage permissive -a httpd_t` to explicitly set the `httpd_t` domain to permissive. Nothing httpd-related is logged in the audit log and the script still doesn't work.

Comment: @yakatz Sorry, I'm at the end of my knowledge of SELinux. I've added the `selinux` tag to the question to try and get you some better help. One last thought, have you checked if `perl` has an selinux domain?

Comment: Once I disabled `httpd_t`, there is nothing else in the audit log, so I don't think it is an `selinux` issue. I am looking deeper into Perl library issues.

Answer (score 1):

We tested by rewriting the same script in Python and PHP. Both of them showed error which pointed us in the right direction.

Python `urllib2` produced the error

```
<class 'urllib2.URLError'>: <urlopen error [Errno 16] Device or resource busy>
      args = (error(16, 'Device or resource busy'),)
      errno = None
      filename = None
      message = ''
      reason = error(16, 'Device or resource busy')
      strerror = None
```

PHP (run as CGI) wouldn't even start:

```
[Wed Jul 25 15:24:52.988582 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 10369] [client 172.28.6.200:44387] AH01215: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so' - libssh2.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Jul 25 15:24:52.988980 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 10369] [client 172.28.6.200:44387] AH01215: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/dba.so' - libtokyocabinet.so.9: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory in Unknown on line 0
    ---- Similar lines for all extensions. ----
```

It appears that [`RLimitMEM`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#rlimitmem) blocks access to shared memory and that is required for opening sockets. I can't find any documentation, but removing that line makes it work.